How to trigger function if no empty rows are left?
Currently, I use the following code to trigger a function if the user inputs a value into cell A1.
I would like to automate this process by triggering the function if no more empty rows are left on the active sheet tab.
Is this possible?
My current code:
if (spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Vocabulary") {
    if(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue() !== "") {
        triggerFunction();
}


Can you confirm what is "no more empty rows are left on the active sheet tab", are you referring about the max row limit for google sheet as your possible data range or do you have a range in mind that you will just consistently check.

Sure! Not referring about the technical row limit, but just that all current rows are filled with data.

The following code will trigger triggerFunction whenever a value is entered in any column of the last empty row in any sheet:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getLastRow() !== sheet.getMaxRows()) return;
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (data.every(row => row.some(cell => cell))) {
    triggerFunction();
  }
}

